# Can i ever get the final Shard in the Walse Tower?

Tags: final-fantasy-5

When the Water Crystal Shatters one of the shards ends up on a ledge, i've learned hidden passages and have it set but i can't find any way of reaching it.

I am wondering if later in the game i can somehow get it or weather it's not possible to obtain it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you can!  But it won't happen until super late in the game.  Spoilers ahead:

> Once the world gets ruined, you can take the sub down to where the tower used to be.  You'll have a strict time limit, but at the bottom of the tower, you can get the shard by fighting Gogo.  Winning against him means you'll get the shard.  I'd recommend equipping the Sprint Shoes ability, to ensure you have plenty of time to get everything in the tower.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it at that point. You get it later in the game.

> The shard is for the job, Mime.